# How to retrieve image files from mongodb to html page

Tags: python, django, image, mongodb, gridfs

I have successfully stored image files in mongdb in binary format.but when i m getting image from mongodb i m getting the same banary format.But i need this image file.Please someone could help

## This is the code i used

```
def retrieve(request):

  db=pymongo.connection.Connection('localhost',27017).demo1
  grid=gridfs.GridFS(db)
  output=grid.get_last_version(filename='shiva.jpg')
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: I have no experience with Python in a web development context, but could it be possible that you need to set the mime-type in the header of the HTTP response to `image/jpeg` so the users web browser knows that it receives an image?

Comment: Hope my answer in another question may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077720/pymongo-bson-binary-save-and-retrieve/42950170#42950170

Comment: Hope my answer in another question may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077720/pymongo-bson-binary-save-and-retrieve/42950170#42950170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i have successfully inserted and retrieved image from mongodb with python..

```
def insert_image(request):
    with open(request.GET["image_name"], "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    print encoded_string
    abc=db.database_name.insert({"image":encoded_string})
    return HttpResponse("inserted")

def retrieve_image(request):
    data = db.database_name.find()
    data1 = json.loads(dumps(data))
    img = data1[0]
    img1 = img['image']
    decode=img1.decode()
    img_tag = '<img alt="sample" src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(decode)
    return HttpResponse(img_tag)
```

Comment: sorry I'm new to python, what is "rb"? and does "image_name" refer to the name of the vairable in which we stored the image?

Comment: dumps(data) what does it mean ?