# Pymongo BSON Binary save and retrieve?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I'm working in Python with MongoDB trying to save an array of floats tightly.

I can **Create and store correctly ***

but **I CANNOT RETRIEVE THE DATA IN A USABLE FORMAT.**

```
>>> import random, array, pymongo
>>> from bson.binary import Binary as BsonBinary
>>> con = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
>>> mm = con['testDatabase']
>>> vals = [random.random() *100 for x in range(1, 5)]
>>> vals
[2.9962593, 64.5582810776, 32.3781311717, 82.0606953423]
>>> varray = array.array('f', vals)
>>> varray
array('f', [2.9962593, 64.5582810776, 32.3781311717, 82.0606953423])
>>> vstring = varray.tostring()
>>> vstring
'\xb7\xc2?@\xd7\x1d\x81B5\x83\x01B\x13\x1f\xa4B'
>>> vbson = BsonBinary(vstring, 5)
>>> vbson
Binary('\xb7\xc2?@\xd7\x1d\x81B5\x83\x01B\x13\x1f\xa4B', 5)
>>> doc1 = { 'something': 1 , 'else' : vbson}
>>> doc1
{'something': 1, 'else': Binary('\xb7\xc2?@\xd7\x1d\x81B5\x83\x01B\x13\x1f\xa4B', 5)}
>>> mm.test1.insert(doc1)
ObjectID('530f7af1d809d80d3db1f635')
>>> gotdoc = mm.test1.find_one()
>>> gotdoc
{u'_id': ObjectId('530f7af1d809d80d3db1f635'), u'something': 3, u'else': Binary('\xb7\xc2?@\xd7\x1d\x81B5\x83\x01B\x13\x1f\xa4B', 5)}
>>> gotfield = gotdoc['else']
>>> gotfield
Binary('\xb7\xc2?@\xd7\x1d\x81B5\x83\x01B\x13\x1f\xa4B', 5)
>>> from bson import BSON
>>> BSON.decode(gotfield)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method decode() must be called with BSON instance as first argument (got Binary instance instead)
>>> gotfield.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

**Once I get my Python string back, I can get my array of random floats back.  But how?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through the errors:

1. The first error appears simply because you need an actual BSON object. Note, that you have never encoded any data - creating `bson.binary.Binary` object does not mean invoking `BSON.encode()`.
2. And that is where PyMongo cheats you a bit. The `bson.binary.Binary` is a runtime-patched `str` or `bytes` instance ([see source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/binary.py)). That is why you get the second error: what you call is actually `str.decode()`, not `BSON.decode()`. So, `gotfield` *contains* the random float data you've stored initially, but the object itself has some different methods (e.g. `repr()`) bound to it.

Comment: This makes sense, but what's the fix? How do you go from bson.binary.Binary back to whatever the original dtype was? Can it be done using cPickle or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

I'm coming~ I just find a way. Hope this may help you somehow.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
```

save image:

```
content = StringIO(f.read())

c = dict(
    content=bson.binary.Binary(content.getvalue()),
)
# insert dict into my database, sha1 is primary key
image_data[sha1] = c
```

retrieve image:

```
f = image_data[sha1]
image = Image.open(StringIO(f['content']))
```

----EDIT----

If you want to return an image from web servers.Do like this:

```
f = image_data[sha1]
# f['mime'] is the type of image, for example 'png'.
resp = Response(f['content'], mimetype='image/' + f['mime'])
return resp
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array.fromstring` for the final decoding stage. I can get to the same spot you're at like so:

```
>>> from bson import Binary
>>> import array
>>> gotstring = Binary('\xb7\xc2?@\xd7\x1d\x81B5\x83\x01B\x13\x1f\xa4B', 5)
```

And finally:

```
>>> a = array.array('f')
>>> a.fromstring(gotstring)
>>> a
array('f', [2.9962594509124756, 64.55828094482422, 32.37813186645508, 82.0606918334961])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the array before storing it, and should not use the array.tostring. Please have a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/#python).

```python
from bson import BSON
bson_string = BSON.encode({"hello": "world"})
>>> bson_string
'\x16\x00\x00\x00\x02hello\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00\x00'
>>> bson_string.decode()
{u'hello': u'world'}
```

Comment: I did not need the bson encoding of a data structure. I have a validly encoded and stored Binary object.  I need to convert it back to the same thing I put in.  So, apparently, BSON.encode/decode is NOT the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

> BSON.decode(gotfield)

it has a TypeError problem,and you should write it like that below

> BSON.decode(bson.BSON(gotfield))

Answer (score 0):

Came to that question as first in search. I had the problem to decode `bson.binary.Binary` to `str` for API response.

As solution I converted it to uuid and then just into str.

```
bson_object = .....
print(
    str(bson_object.to_uuid())
)
```