# Retrieve stored image from mongodb using python

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, gridfs

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import numpy as np
import gridfs 

import os,os.path
i=0
try:
    for file in os.listdir("/Users/sarthakgupta/Desktop/sae/Images"):
        if (file.endswith(".png") | file.endswith(".jpg")):
            filename = "/Users/sarthakgupta/Desktop/sae/Images/"+file
            datafile =  open(filename,"rb")
            thedata = datafile.read()
            datafile.close()


            c = MongoClient()
            i=i+1
            db = c.trial5
            fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
            t = "class"+str(i)


            stored = fs.put(thedata,filename=q)

except IOError:
    print("Image file %s not found" %datafile)
    raise SystemExit
```

I stored image in a mongo db . Now i want to retrieve those images from database by the filename and to store the image(or pixels) of same filename in an array or list.  Suppose if there is 2 images with filename "class1",then they should be in one array.

Comment: Hope my answer in another question may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077720/pymongo-bson-binary-save-and-retrieve/42950170#42950170

Comment: What is "q" here in filename=q?

Comment: I found q should be replaced by t instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `fs` variable like before, and:

```
data = fs.get_last_version(filename).read()
```

You could also query for a list of files like:

```
from bson import Regex
for f in fs.find({'filename': Regex(r'.*\.(png|jpg)')):
    data = f.read()
```

Also, a comment about your code: it's very slow to recreate the MongoClient and GridFS instances for every iteration of your loop. Create them once before you start looping, and reuse them.

Comment: When i use :
'data = fs.get_last_version(filename='class3')
print(data)'
i get the output : <gridfs.grid_file.GridOut object at 0x105279e80> .  
What does this mean ?
and when i use 'data = fs.get_last_version(filename='class3').read()
print(data)'. 
I get the output "b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x00XExif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x02\x0......" in this form. How can i use this output ?.. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: "data" is the byte contents of the image. You could save those contents to a file named "image.jpg" or do whatever you want with them.

Comment: But when i tried to display the image using open cv , i get an error " a bytes-like object is required, not 'GridOut' " .  Here's my code. 

nparr = np.fromstring(data1, np.uint8)
img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
print(img_np)

Comment: `f` is a GridOut object. `f.read()` is the contents of the image. Pass `f.read()` to OpenCV.

Comment: the for loop method is still showing error illegal expression on Regex.