# how to retrieve image from mongodb using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, gridfs

i store the image in mongodb using python withgridfs
now how to retrieve that image

```
   db = MongoClient().myDB
   fs = gridfs.GridFS( db )
   fileID = fs.put( open( self.filename, 'rb') )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve stored image from mongodb using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276665/retrieve-stored-image-from-mongodb-using-python)

Comment: thanks kate for your support