# Retrieve and show image from MongoDB using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, image, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using PyMongo to retrieve collection data as dictionary and then trying to convert the image key's respective value from the dict to proper base64 encoded string to show the image, but it doesn't just work. When I use mongoengine, it works fine as the string returned from the latter is b64 encoded already, unlike PyMongo.

Following is my sample working Mongoengine code to retrieve a respective image and show as Pillow image:

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, fields
import mongoengine
import io
import PIL.Image as Image

print(mongoengine.__version__)

# To save image
connect(db='video_analytics', host='127.0.0.1', port=27017)


class User(Document):
    meta = {"collection": "users"}
    username = fields.StringField(required=True)
    profile_image = fields.ImageField(thumbnail_size=(150, 150, False))


user = User.objects(username='Doggy').first()
# print(user)
img_data = user.profile_image.read()

# Test
print(img_data)
# Ends

bytes = bytearray(img_data)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes))
print(image)
# image.show()
```

And following is my PyMongo code which gives no error but doesn't show the image:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/")
# select database
db = client['frame_read']
# select the collection within the database
test = db["random"]
# print("collections count -->" + str(test.count()))
cursor = test.find()
for rec in cursor:
    # print(rec['profile_image'])
    f = rec['profile_image']
    img = Image.open(f)
    print(img.size)
    img.show()
```

I tried many ways, but it is just not working. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077720/pymongo-bson-binary-save-and-retrieve) I read by default MongoDB stores in BSON bytes format. Is there a way how to retrieve data properly?

I followed [this](https://www.kaggle.com/restlessrational/viewing-bytes-as-images-retrieved-from-bson-dump) too, but to no avail.

Note: I'm intentionally not using GridFS because my image size is much lesser than 16 MB. If you say GridFS is still better performant for retrieval, then I shall plan using the same.

Comment: You do not need to use gridfs but you do need to include details as to what is not working for this question to be answerable.

Comment: Image isn't showing up using img.show(), probably because I'm unable to provide the  expected type of data to Image.open().

Comment: What type is expected, what type are you providing, etc.

Comment: Updated the question.