# Store images in MongoDB python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

So I've been trying to create a database that has the structure like: 
Name - Image - Description of the celeb.
I've been struggling to store the images on my DB. 
When I retrieve images, it displays a blank image.

```
import hashlib
import requests
from IPython.display import Image
from IMDb_Bollywood_Celebrity import Scrape_info
from mongoengine import connect, Document, fields

connect(db='Bollywood_Celebs_Database', host="127.0.0.1", port=27017)


class dataB(Document):
    meta = {"collection": "Celebs"}
    celeb_name = fields.StringField(required=True)
    upload_image = fields.ImageField(thumbnail_size=(140, 209, False))
    description = fields.StringField()


si = Scrape_info()

for i in range(len(si.Names) - 1):
    upload = dataB(celeb_name=si.Names[i], description=si.final_info[i])
    for img in si.image_save:
        celeb_image = open(img, 'rb')
        upload.upload_image.replace(celeb_image, filename=si.Names[i])
    upload.save()

# Retrieve images

for celeb in si.bollywood_dictionary["Names"]:
    cb = dataB.objects(celeb_name=celeb).first()
Image(cb.upload_image.read())
```

Comment: Are you trying to store the images as links to there locations or actual raw binary files?

Also have you seen these articles before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077720/pymongo-bson-binary-save-and-retrieve/42950170#42950170
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718251/how-to-retrieve-image-files-from-mongodb-to-html-page

Comment: Or have you though about using GridFS? Alot of the documentation I have been reading points to using that library for things along these lines